# Can an 'Abstract' parameter be passed to pandoc to create a latex file?

Tags: conversion, abstract, pandoc

Similar to `$title$`, `$author$`, and `$date$`, is there an `$abstract$` parameter that one can pass to a latex file from the title block? Example:

```
\begin{abstract}
    $abstract$
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: There's been [a thread about it in `pandoc-discuss` list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/pandoc-discuss/vVX60y-0Vzo/discussion)

Comment: Although you've gotten an answer from Paulo here, questions about pandoc's input are generally off-topic here as they don't really involve TeX and therefore you would be more likely to get help on the pandoc mailing list that henrique links to.

Answer (score 11):

I had a look at the documentation and found out that you can easily set new variables. Sadly, I don't think `pandoc` is able to automatically extract custom variables, since the documentation states that some variables are automatically set, other aren't.

We can extend `default.latex` from `$PANDOC_HOME/templates` to include an `abstract` verification. I made a copy from `https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex` and added the following code before the `$body$` markup:

```
...    
$if(abstract)$

\begin{abstract}
$abstract$
\end{abstract}
$endif$

$body$
...
```

I saved my new file as `article.latex`. Now I can call:

```
$ pandoc --template=article.latex --variable abstract="I'm an abstract" INPUT -o OUTPUT.tex
```

The new block

```
\begin{abstract}
I'm an abstract
\end{abstract}
```

will be available in the generated file.

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: Gracias. Helped quite much. Not exactly what I'm looking for though, since you're passing the abstract in as arguments, whereas I want to define ALL my variables and parameters at the beginning of the .rst file in the header.